# need to run chgrp as root on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I need `git` user to run

```
chgrp -R www-data linode.git/
chmod -R 770 linode.git/
```

as **root**. Only these two commands and only for git user. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add git to sudoers using `visudo`. The lines you should add will look something like this:

```
git hostname = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/chgrp -R www-data /path/to/linode.git/, /bin/chmod -R 770 /path/to/linode.git/
```

Comment: I used joe to edit the sudoer file. I hope that's fine. When I run the chgrp command I get this error `chgrp: changing group of `linode.git/objects/pack': Operation not permitted`. If I run the comman as root it works.

Comment: @Radek: You should do `EDITOR=joe sudo visudo`. If you don't use `visudo` bad things could happen (see `man visudo`). Are you doing `sudo -u git chgrp ...` when logged in as yourself or `sudo chgrp ...` as the user "git"? In either case, you have to use `sudo`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: if I copy the line you gave me into sudoers I get this error on saving. `>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 18 <<<`

Comment: strange but this one works `git    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/chgrp`

Comment: I strongly recommend using full paths for _all_ file or directory references in the sudo string.  E.g '/bin/chgrp -r www-data /var/local/linode.git/'

Comment: @Slartibartfast: what if I need the user to change a group for two or more directories?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using super, a handy tool which is basically setuid but you can limit it to certain users or groups.
I'm actually using it for this exact purpose.